# Check pointwise convergence and uniform convergence of $f_n(x) = n^3x\exp(-nx^2)$ on $[0,1]$

Tags: analysis, uniform-convergence

> Check pointwise convergence and uniform convergence of $f_n(x) =
>  n^3x\exp(-nx^2)$  on $[0,1]$

Pointwise convergence:
$$ \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} f_n(x) =  \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}  n^3x\exp(-nx^2) =\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}  \exp(ln(n^3x))\exp(-nx^2)  = \\ =
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}  \exp(\ln(n^3x)-nx^2) = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}  \exp(3\ln(n) + ln(x) - nx^2) = 0$$

so if $f_n$ converges uniformly  to $f$ then for any $\varepsilon > 0$ there is $n_0$ that for any $n>n_0$ and $x \in \mathbb R$ 
$$ 
\exp(3\ln(n) + ln(x) - nx^2) < \varepsilon
$$
so I choose $\varepsilon = 1$ and I try to show that there is no $n_0$. Let $x = \frac1{\sqrt{n}}$
$$\exp(3\ln(n) + ln(\frac1{\sqrt{n}}) - 1) = \exp(3\ln(n)  -\frac12\ln(n) - 1)  = \exp(\ln(n^\frac52)  - ln(e)) = \frac{n^\frac52}{e} > 1 $$ for $n>1$. So if I am right then $f_n$ convergence pointwise  and do not  convergence uniformly.

However, there is different answer in my book (convergence pointwise  and  uniformly), so where I am wrong?

Comment: But "Weierstrass M-test is a test for  **infinite series**" not for sequences.

Comment: The pointwise limit is zero. The uniform limit, if it exists, must be the same as the pointwise limit. So the suggestion given is to compute $\max_{x \in [0,1]} |f_n(x)|$ and see if it goes to zero as $n \to \infty$. Although this approach frequently doesn't work simply because you can't compute the maximum, in this case I think it works out.

Comment: $\sup|f_n(x)-f(x)|\to 0 \implies \{f_n\} $ is uniform convergent

Comment: Actually, this is pretty much what you did; you didn't find the exact maximum, but you "morally" found the maximum (the actual maximum is apparently at $x=1/\sqrt{2n}$). So I think you're done.

Comment: Easier just to calculate $f_n(1/\sqrt n)$ directly with no $log$s necessary.

Comment: So the answer is $ f_n$ convergence pointwise and do not convergence uniformly? If so I apologize for the unnecessary occupying your time.

Comment: @ dyrAnd)      Yes......